# Why are Moshe, Aharon, David and Shlomo mentioned in the prayer for the sick?

Tags: tefilla, moshe-rabbeinu, choleh-sick, king-david, aharon

Based on Nusach Ashkenaz, it seems that when there is a prayer beginning with the words מי שברך , that only the 3 fathers (Avraham, Yitzhak and Ya'akov) are mentioned. Two examples:

- Mi Sheberach for someone [called to the Torah](http://www.egabbai.com/base.shtml?oleh)
- Mi Sheberach after the second "Yekum Purkan"

However, when reciting Mi Sheberach [for the ill](http://chayimaruchim.com/uploads/images_products/MI%20SHEBEIRACH.pdf), in addition to the forefathers, Moses, Aaron, David and Solomon are added.

- Why are these 4 added, in particular?
- How are these 4 "related" to the ill or help the ill recover?

Comment: FWIW, I've been to many Orthodox schuls (mostly RCA types) where the imahot are also added, does this affect your question at all?

Comment: @NoachmiFrankfurt Not really. I agree that adding the mothers is something I've seen in Conservative, Havurah, "Progressive" minyanim, etc. Regardless, my question is on common usage that has these specific people. Aside, check out home page of Beurei Hatefilah which has a link to a book on Minhagei Frankfurt. You may be interested in viewing it.

Comment: I actually have a modern, partial edition of Divrei Kehillaus. My Rashi needs some work, although this should be invaluable for my Jeckisch minhogimbuch.

Comment: Why list anyone's name at all? The whole phrase "Mishebeirach A B C D E" is just a stand-in for God. He Who blessed Abraham is identical to He Who blessed Isaac is identical to He Who blessed Mordechai.

Comment: @DoubleAA I think your missing the emphasis of my question. The other ones have the 1st three. For Cholim, we're adding 4 more.

Comment: +1 I think the phraseology is the same for the misheberach for those who don't talk in shul (for those that say it). I know one Rabbi who skips the name Moshe on that list. Never asked him why....

Comment: @user6591 My theory as to why Moshe is not on that list. He was both a humble man as well as a stutterer. Thus, it's a given that he spoke only when he needed to, and even then, at times, he was silent. For example, when his brother and sister spoke badly about him, he should have said something to defend himself, but didn't.